# Application of fubinis theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

I have a question about a finite $\sigma$ measure on $(\mathbb{R^+}, B(\mathbb{R^+}))$:

$Show\  that\ 2\int_{\mathbb{R^+}}x\mu([x,\infty[)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R^+}}x^2\mu(dx)$

I know that I should use fubini, but unfortunately I don't know where to start.
Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$$$
Notice that
$$\mathbf{1}_{[x,\infty)}(y)=\begin{cases}
1&y\geq x\\
0 &y<x\end{cases}=\mathbf{1}_{(0,y]}(x)$$
which implies:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x\mathbf{1}_{[x,\infty)}(y)dx=\int_{(0,y]}xdx=\frac{y^2}{2}$$
So
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}x\mu([x,\infty))dx&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x\mathbf{1}_{[x,\infty)}(y)\mu(dy)dx=\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x\mathbf{1}_{[x,\infty)}(y)dx\mu(dy)=\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\frac{y^2}{2}\mu(dy)
\end{aligned}$$
where $(1)$ is by Fubini-Tonelli.